# JQuery plugins and prototype, exposing methods

Tags: javascript, jquery, prototype

I have this really old unmaintained plugin which in a nutshell is structured like this:

[image: plugin code]

The plugin itself work fine, but I need to access some of the prototype methods.

```
var $el = $.find('myEl');
$el.searchlight(foo, bar);
$el.clearResults() //this throws an exception
```

When I call a prototype method I get an exception that the method doesn't exist. Did I get something completely wrong with prototype or am I just using it the wrong way.(I can hack the library if that's required since it's unmaintained for 7 years now).

An additional question would be how I can make the initializer return the element itself, would I just have to add 'return this.each' as last statement in $.fn.searchlight?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To solve this you could store the instance of the plugin within a `data` attribute on the element. You can then call methods on that function as required, something like this:

```
// in plugin:
$.fn.searchLight = function(url, options) {
    return this.each(function() {
        $(this).data('searchlight', new SearchLight(this, url, options));
    });
};

// in the calling code, instantiate
var $el = $('.searchLightElement').searchLight(foo, bar);

// then use the methods of the plugin
$el.data('searchlight').clearResults();
```

[**Working example**](https://jsfiddle.net/shq8n0b1/)

Comment: Thanks !! I didnt't even know you can save instances on data. I actually had to play around with your fiddle (setting some members in constructor and geting them in clear) to actually believe this works xD. Kudos for teaching me I concept I didn't even know existed.

Comment: No problem, glad to help. It's one of the nicest benefits of jQuery caching data attributes in an object - you can store any data type in there, and retrieve it exactly as it was stored